# Scrollbar between table header and body

Tags: jquery, css, html

This is what i want to achieve, I have been able to achieve table with fixed headers, scroll bar on top and bottom, however i want the scrollbar to appear in the middle. Any thoughts ?

```
________________
|    Headers    |
|---------------|
| <-Scrollbar-> |
| --------------|
| Table Body    |
|_______________|
```

Comment: Got any code/jsfiddle to show for?

Comment: is the scroll bar supposed to be scrolling the header horizontally? scrolling the body horizontally? scrolling both? something else? what?

Comment: Like this? http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

Comment: Maybe a way to achieve this is to use two separate tables and javascript to scroll them at once.